# Should expansion gaps in an OSB3 roof be filled before installing EPDM roofing?

Tags: sheathing

I've boarded a roof in OSB3 prior to laying an EDPM membrane. I've left 3mm expansion gaps between boards. Should these be filled with anything prior to covering?

Answer (score 4):

Gaps between the sheets are specified by the manufacturer because the gap allows for a bit of movement - expansion, in particular - to be absorbed without causing any buckling in the roof deck. If the gaps are filled, whether with sawdust, other debris, or an intentional sealant, then their ability to absorb expansion will be compromised.

Laying an EPDM membrane directly over the panels does pose a challenge: the gaps between panels may telegraph through the membrane and this may be unsightly. Ask the membrane supplier for a recommendation. For example, they might suggest applying some kind of tape over the OSB joint gaps and possibly applying a mastic over the tape to smooth it further.

Answer (score 4):

In the end I decided it didn't matter too much (it's a workshop and day to day no one will see the roof). I put some scrim tape over half the roof, and nothing over the other half. I can't tell the difference between them.

It was a windy day when I glued the EDPM down, and this caused the membrane to be slightly lifted rather than depressed over the gaps. However, the membrane tightens up with time anyway. Most of the ripples have now gone.

Comment: Thanks for bringing this info back; if you think it's the best answer you can mark it as "accepted" by clicking the checkmark.

Comment: "For both wood or concrete roofs, caulk all gaps greater than 1/4” as well as transitions between the roof and walls or skylights." – http://www.conservationtechnology.com/documents/EPDMRoofingHandbook0408.pdf - 3mm is slightly less than 1/8".

Comment: If you want to post that as an answer, I'll happily accept it.